# Getting ProductNotSupportedError: The client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this unknown product

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, egg

Upgraded the midwayjs service from v2 to v3 but now I am unable to connect to elasticsearch.
Below is the package.json dependencies:

```
"@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.12.0",
"egg": "^3.3.3",
"egg-elasticsearch-ts": "^1.1.1"
```

> Getting below error:
>
> fetch fs status error ProductNotSupportedError: The client noticed
> that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this
> unknown product.
> at Transport.request
>
> meta: {
> body: null,
> statusCode: null,
> headers: null,
> meta: {
> context: null,
> request: [Object],
> name: 'elasticsearch-js',
> connection: null,
> attempts: 0,
> aborted: false
> }
> }
> }

Comment: what is your elasticsearch version ? are you using AWS Elasticsearch / Opensearch ?

Comment: "number" : "7.10.2"

Comment: This is expected as you are using 7.12 version of the python client. You should use 7.10 version of python client and it will resolved your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using 7.10 version of ElasticSearch and elastic client is 7.12 hence it is throwing this exception.

Please remove the ElasticSearch client 7.12 and install ElasticSearch client 7.10 version which will resolved your issue.

Also, my understanding is that you are using AWS ElasticSearch service which is now AWS OpenSearch.

**Update:**

As you mentioned in comment that you are using Opensearch 2.0.1 version hence you need to use [Opensearch Javascript client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/) insted of Elasticsearch client.

Comment: Sorry I am bit new in this but what is the difference in normal elastic search client and elasticsearch python client ? And how that will resolve this issue ? Also, can you please share the npm link for the same (elasticsearch python client).

Comment: Sorry brother... I thought you are using Python so i mentioned about python client. I have updated my answer. You need to use Elastic JS Client version 7.10 insted of 7.12 as you are using NodeJS.

Comment: getting same error after downgrading to "@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.10.0",

Comment: where is your elasticsearch is running ? is it on local or AWS elasticsearch service ?

Comment: its running in aws (opensearch: 2.0.1).

Comment: Ahh that is the reson you are getting this error. You need to use [Opensearch Javascript client](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/) insed of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Great to know that it helps you. Could you please mark as solution / answer if it really helps you.